# How can I remove multiple occurrences from a string in python?

Tags: python

I have a string like 'AABA'. I want to remove multiple occurances by removing others. The result should be 'AB'.
Sample Input: AABA
Sample Output: AB

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate characters? Try adding another example.

Answer (score 0):

If the order doesn't matter, use a set.

```py
word = "AABA"
new_word = "".join(set(word))
```

If the order DOES matter, use an Ordered Dictionary (from collections library).

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

word = "AABA"
new_word = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(word))
```

EDIT: Consult the link posted in the comments above - it gives the same advice, but explains it better.

Comment: This answer is the same as the answer posted in the duplicate question

Comment: Oh wow you're right. There's is more thorough as well.